# ¿Como hacer un ng-selected="true" desde un controladorjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Tengo un formulario con datos precargados de una DB que debo actualizar en el html. 
Hay un dropdown de provincias en html crudo donde aplico un llamado en angularjs a un segundo dropdown de localidades y quiero poder marcar que provincia fue seleccionada por defecto al cargarse la pagina mediante un ng-init (donde inyecto los datos precargados).
Al utilizar angular para traer las localidades, ya no puedo utilizar un simple if de php para indicar "selected" en el option de provincias, sino que parece que el tema es por js.(si pongo ng-model=provincias)
En el controlador de js me llega el valor de la provincia seleccionada desde el ng-init (se lo inyecto al cargar la pagina), pero no entiendo como darle la orden para que lo seleccione, ya que me aparece vacio el option.

```
<select class="form-control" name="provincia" id="provincia" ng-
model="provincia"  ng-change="selectorLocalidad()">
 <option value="1">CABA</option>
 <option value="2">BUENOS AIRES</option>
 <option value="3">CATAMARCA</option>
 <option value="16">CHACO</option>
 <option value="17">CHUBUT</option>
 <option value="4">CORDOBA</option>
 <option value="5">CORRIENTES</option>
</select>
```

Algo asi, desde el controlador js que es donde tengo el dato de la opcion ya seleccionada, por ejemplo, el 4, pero en el html nunca me lo selecciona:

$scope.provincia= selected.4.true;

como para que me seleccione por default Cordoba.

Agradeceré me iluminen.

Comment: esto no funciona $scope.provincia.selectedOption = true;

Comment: ahora ya probando directamente sobre el html (aunque mi intención es desde el controlador), me doy cuenta que estas dos opciones tampoco me seleccionan nada :

Comment: <option value="4" selected>CORDOBA</option>
 <option value="5" ng-selected="true">CORRIENTES</option>

Answer (score 0):

finalmente encontré que para precargar el dropdown html con un option seleccionado, se hace con ng-init:

```
<select class="form-control" name="provincias" id="provincias" ng-model="provincias"  ng-change="selectorLocalidades()" ng-init="provincias='5'">
```

agregando  ng-init="provincias='4'" en el select, y no desde el controlador. Esto hace que la provincia de CORDOBA ya este seleccionada.

Comment: haz probado ng-select? https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select